# Fake routes (lat long) lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

Is there a lib that manages fake routes and gives me all the points (latitude longitude) of this route? For example a land route from Lisbon to Paris.
For nodeJS preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API with https://openrouteservice.org/services/ to get routes. I don't know exactly what you mean by Fake routes, but you can get several alternative routes returned in the call.